# Increase the performance of this script

Tags: php

So i made this script that gets the most used color in an image. Problem is, they way i coded it makes it very useless.

The script can only find the color on a small image. The large ones creates this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)
```

I insert the HEX value of each pixle in a array. This is the problem, how should i do it so avoid getting to large arrays?

The script:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/2.jpg");

function common($img) {
    $w = imagesx($img);
    $h = imagesy($img);
    $r = $g = $b = 0;
    $count = 0;

    $array = array();

    for($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {
        for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $r += $rgb >> 16;
            $g += $rgb >> 8 & 255;
            $b += $rgb & 255;
            $hex = "#";
            $hex.= str_pad(dechex($r), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $hex.= str_pad(dechex($g), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $hex.= str_pad(dechex($b), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $array[$count++] = $hex;
        }
    }

    $result = array_count_values($array);
    asort($result);
    end($result);
    $answer = key($result);

    return $answer;
}

$common = common($im);
echo $common;
```

Comment: The error just means that PHP has run out of memory. Working with images takes quite a lot of memory. You can increase the memory that PHP is allowed to use [in your php.ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits).

Comment: Dont really get why this guy gets -4. The error isn't a really common one and the question is pretty formulated altough the question is kind of like:"Make this for me" but still not a bad error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving every pixel in the array, why not insert only one element for every different color with a counter? Something like:

```
if ( !isset( $array[$hex] ) )
{
    $array[$hex] = 1;
}
else
{
    $array[$hex]++;
}
```

This way you could just find the color in the array with the highest count:

```
$highest_hex = "";
$highest_count = 0;
foreach($array AS $hex => $count)
{
    if ( $count > $highest_count )
    {
        $highest_hex = $hex;
        $highest_count = $count;
    }
}

echo "The most used color has hex code {$highest_hex} and was used {$highest_count} times.";
```

This is a dictionary-like (key-value) approach. Note that this array will be smaller than yours in average, but its worst case will be the same length as yours (when all pixels have a different color without repetitions). In that case the first color found in the image (the first pixel at top-left) will be considered "the most used".

Answer (score 0):

A more memory-efficient way to do this would be to create an array containing the colors in the document and increment a color each time it is seen.

In pseudo-code:

```
$colors=array();
for(;$i<count($pixels);$i++){
    $pixel=$pixels[$i];
    if(isset($colors[getcolor($pixels[$i])]){
        $colors[getcolor($pixels[$i]++;
    }else{
        $colors[getcolor($pixels[$i]=1;
    }
}
```

and then get the array element with the highest number.